# Can I still downgrade from iOS 6.1.3 to iOS 6.1.2 (iPhone 4)?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I am trying to jailbreak a friend's 16GB iPhone 4. It's currently running iOS 6.1.3.

I'm aware that you can't jailbreak 6.1.3, so I am attempting to downgrade to 6.1.2, however I am having an issue creating or finding SHSH blobs for redsn0w to complete the downgrade.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: No SHSH blobs = no downgrade. Sorry.

Comment: You can Jailbreak it also on 6.1.3 with http://p0sixspwn.com/ - so you don't need a Downgrad ...  EDIT.1 - you can only get SHSH Blobs from the Phone you have - this SHSH Blobs are Unique - so "finding" some for 6.1.2 on the .net won't help you - sorry

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [firmware signing status for iPhone 4](http://www.icj.me/ios/all#iPhone31), only iOS versions from 7 and up are being signed by Apple.

In order to use `redsn0w` to do a downgrade, you need the SHSH blobs saved for the specific version that you wish to downgrade to. In this case, it seems like they were never saved while the phone was on iOS 6.1.2. So you cannot create/retrieve them.

Comment: I forget, can you use redsn0w to preserve the baseband, boot it into pwned DFU mode, and use iTunes with the option key to downgrade? Or is that only for the iPhone 3GS and below?

Answer (score 0):

A jailbreak now exists for all 6.1.x iOS versions: http://p0sixspwn.com/

There is very little reason to downgrade from one 6.1.x revision to another; doing so would actually cause you to lose out on some important security patches.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot *downgrade* right now, as Apple has stopped signing iOS below version 7 now. Your best, if you want to jailbreak, is then to wait till a stable release is given out.

Comment: there will never be a newer Jailbreak for 6.1.3 - i don't know any Group or "Hacker" with interests of another 6.1.x Jailbreak

Comment: The timeframe of the question asked and the answer thus given was when iOS 7 was just released mate, I think your answer and comments are just a little late, by a year or so.